# Crear lista con las posiciones múltiples de 7 de una lista ya creada?

Tags: python, lista

Necesitaria saber de la siguiente lista:

`list = ['FIAT', 'FORD', 'GENESIS', 'GMC', 'HONDA', 'HYUNDAI', 'INFINITI', 'JAGUAR', 'JEEP', 'KIA', 'LAMBORGHINI', 'LAND ROVER', 'LEXUS', 'LINCOLN', 'MASERATI', 'MAZDA', 'MERCEDES-BENZ', 'MINI', 'MITSUBISHI', 'NISSAN', 'PORSCHE', 'RAM', 'ROLLS-ROYCE', 'SCION', 'SMART', 'SRT', 'SUBARU', 'TOYOTA', 'VOLKSWAGEN', 'VOLVO']`

Mostrar sólo las posiciones múltiples de 7, estoy intentando lo siguiente:
`list_seven = [i for i,x in list.index if x % 7]`

Me da error porque me falta algun elemento que indique que sea la posición pensaba que seria poniendo el list.index, alguien me puede echar una mano?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Para iterar una lista a través de sus índices puedes usar el método `enumerate()`

```
list1 = ['FIAT', 'FORD', 'GENESIS', 'GMC', 'HONDA', 'HYUNDAI', 'INFINITI', 'JAGUAR', 'JEEP', 'KIA', 'LAMBORGHINI', 'LAND ROVER', 'LEXUS', 'LINCOLN', 'MASERATI', 'MAZDA', 'MERCEDES-BENZ', 'MINI', 'MITSUBISHI', 'NISSAN', 'PORSCHE', 'RAM', 'ROLLS-ROYCE', 'SCION', 'SMART', 'SRT', 'SUBARU', 'TOYOTA', 'VOLKSWAGEN', 'VOLVO']
list_seven  = [num for x,num in enumerate(list1) if x % 7 == 0]
```

Esto te devolverá una lista con los datos que están en los índices múltiplos de 7 (Ojo, el índice 0 también cumple con la condición `x % 7 == 0`

Answer (score 3):

Puedes hacer slicing de la lista indicando los pasos en el tercer parámetro. La notación es `[inicio:fin:pasos]`

```
lista = ['FIAT', 'FORD', 'GENESIS', 'GMC', 'HONDA', 'HYUNDAI', 'INFINITI', 'JAGUAR', 'JEEP', 'KIA', 'LAMBORGHINI', 'LAND ROVER', 'LEXUS', 'LINCOLN', 'MASERATI', 'MAZDA', 'MERCEDES-BENZ', 'MINI', 'MITSUBISHI', 'NISSAN', 'PORSCHE', 'RAM', 'ROLLS-ROYCE', 'SCION', 'SMART', 'SRT', 'SUBARU', 'TOYOTA', 'VOLKSWAGEN', 'VOLVO']
list_seven = lista[::7]
```

Comment: Imposible más corto.